# Using SuperClass as reference instead of SubClass?

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance

To implement a Queue, why do we use?

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

I mean a Superclass reference, why don't we use a LinkedList reference?

Comment: that's an interface. also, possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194278/should-you-always-code-to-interfaces-in-java).

Comment: yes Queue is an interface and we cannot instantiate it,but while LinkedList has all the methods implemented,why not LinkedList as a reference

Comment: You can use the subClass as well. The reason why we use the super one is we can process it regardless of which specific sub one it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid unnecessary restrictions

You should always try to declare your variables with the least unnecessary restriction; often that means to an interface like Queue or Collection. This allows you to more easily change your implementation. I will use two classes from the collections framework as my example but the principle is general.

Imagine the following objective:

> I need 2 collections that can have objects added to it. And I also
> need to be able to find which objects are in both collections. So in
> other words I need the following methods

```
Collection#add
Collection#retainAll
```

These are both within Collection so any collection will do. Collection is an interface so I need to choose a concrete implementation. I choose ArrayList, on a whim. My code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Collection<Integer> a=new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<Integer> b=new ArrayList<>();
    
    initialise(a);
    initialise(b);
    testRetain(a,b);
}

public static void initialise(Collection<Integer> collection){
    Random rnd=new Random();
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        collection.add(rnd.nextInt());
    }
}

public static void testRetain(Collection<Integer> collection1, Collection<Integer> collection2){
    collection1.removeAll(collection2);
}
```

This code works fine and does exactly what I asked it to do. However; in profiling I find that it is a bottleneck. So I test out different implentations of the Collection class and profile the results.

[image]

As you can see, for the retainAll operation the HashSet turned out to be much better. So I can change my implementation by changing just `new ArrayList<>();` to `new HashSet<>();` in one place. No need to change every other method I've used to `HashSet` as well because they don't care, as long as they get some sort of `Collection` they are happy

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Collection<Integer> a=new HashSet<>();
    Collection<Integer> b=new HashSet<>();

    initialise(a); //<--no need to alter this method
    initialise(b);
    testRetain(a,b); //<--no need to alter this method
}
```

Well that was easy. Now imagine a much larger application with dozens of methods; all of which could be hardcoded to use `ArrayList` even though they didn't need to, all of which you would now need to manually alter.

Answer (score 1):

We have a design principle called **Code to interfaces never with concrete implementations**

Here Queue is an Interface which can hold implementation class

Advantages over above principle

1.Switching between multiple implementations become easy in future

```
 So it is always recommonded to code to interface instead of concrete implementations
```

2.If we won't use above principle we loose key Object oriented concept polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

```
To implement a Queue,why do we use?
```

No one can really assert that this is the patter that everyone must follow. You can very 
well use

```
LinkedListq=new LinkedList();
```

Reason above patter is used frequently because it offers the power of polymorphism. To explain it in short you now need a `LinkedList` but later you may need `PriorityQueue`. To use same reference for multiple concrete classes we use above pattern.