# when to use List, when to use LinkedList ?(java)

Tags: java

I was a bit confused, when we use

```
List<String> lst = new LinkedList<>();
```

when we use

```
LinkedList<String> lklst = new LinkedList<>();
```

At the beginning, I thought they are the same, but today, I realized they are not the same. For example, if I call `lst.getFirst()` It will tell me there is a error. However, if i do `lklst.getFirst()`, it works fine. My question is when do we use lklst then? why they are different? Also, does it apply same rule for Map. THanks!

Comment: @soorapadman totally not that

Comment: Read more on the subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194278/should-you-always-code-to-interfaces-in-java

Comment: When to use `LinkedList` specifically: [rarely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist).

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side you're declaring the type of the variable, `lst`. Since `lst`'s type is `List` you can only access methods of a `List`, even if the object `lst` *points to* is really a `LinkedList`. There's an inherent tradeoff between declaring a variable of a concrete type like `LinkedList` (access to more methods / behavior) vs. a more abstract interface (safer, better compartmentalized code).

This is a big topic, and there isn't one simple answer for when to do one vs. the other (though there's *lots* of advice out there about it!) - you'll need to figure out which is appropriate for your use case.

*[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) - Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces* is a pretty canonical citation for this issue, and as the title implies suggest preferring `List` rather than `LinkedList`.