# what is the best technique of using OOP?

Tags: c#

Can u give a real sample scenario using OOP structure for developing programs.

Would appreciate your response.

Thank you,

Comment: If this is a genuine interest of yours, and not homework or similar, you may find *Design Patterns: Elements of Reuseable Object-Oriented Software"* by Gamma, Helm, Johnson, and Vlissides interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book) It's sometimes called the "Gang of Four" (or even just GoF) book

Answer (score 1):

OOP principle - **[program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean/2697810#2697810)**

[What does "program to interfaces, not implementations" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean/2697810#2697810)

For more of OOAD, read this book. It explains majority OOAD principles and techniques very well.

[image]
<sub>(source: [headfirstlabs.com](http://headfirstlabs.com/Images/hfooad_cover.gif))</sub>