# Implements method of interface, method call and type cast

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Consider the followoing code

```
interface MyInterface{
    void method(String s);// if we write static modifier we have compile error
}
class MyClass implements MyInterface{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        myMethod(new Object());//Compile error
    }
    static void method(String s){...}// compile error
    static void myMethod(Number n){...}

}
```

1. Why we cant define static method in interface?
2. Why we cant implements `method()` with static modifier?
3. When we are calling myMethod with reference to Object we have compile error. As i understood, compiler doesnt cast automatically, isnt it?
4. Consider the following code

   `Object someObj; 
   ...
   Number n= (Number) someObj;`

What compiler is doing when we cast to `Number` in this case?

Comment: See [Why should we declare interface methods as public?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614708/why-should-we-declare-interface-methods-as-public)

Comment: @Smit different topic. not really related to this question

Comment: You're asking a few different questions, each of which should have been asked separately.  The first is possible duplicate of [Why can't I declare static methods in an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21817/1281433).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why we cant define static method in interface?

All the methods of an interface are by default `public abstract`. Using `static` modifier doesn't make sense. Because the invocation of static methods aren't polymorphic. In the sense, you can't override them. You invoke the static methods on the class name only. Well, you can invoke them on some reference too, but that will be ultimately resolved on the basis of the declared type of the reference. Now, since the method is by default abstract, it doesn't make sense to invoke it. It doesn't have any body to do any task.

> Why we cant implements method() with static modifier?

When you try to add `static` modifier to the overridden method, it is not considered as being overriding. So, your class essentially have two different methods, with same name, same parameters, and same return type. That is of course not allowed inside a class.

Note that, you have to explicitly add `public` modifier to the overriding method in the class, else your code won't compile. The reason being, you can't decrease the visibility of the overridden method in the subclass.

> When we are calling myMethod with reference to Object we have compile error. As i understood, compiler doesnt cast automatically, isnt it?

Jave doesn't do automatic narrowing conversion. You need to add cast explicitly. But even if it allowed, how you expect your code to behave, because you are trying to refer a super class object with a subclass reference? You can of course make your code to compile by adding a cast while invoking the method:

```
myMethod((Number)new Object());  // This will compile, but fail at runtime
```

The above invocation will result in a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

However, if you have an `Object` reference refering to an object of any subclass of `Number`, you can add an explicit cast, that will be type safe:

```
Object obj = new Integer(5);
Number num = (Number)obj;  // This is fine. Because `obj` is referring to an `Integer`.
```

And finally, the signature of your `main` method is not correct. You are missing the `public` modifier.

Comment: Note that interfaces as of Java 8 *can* have static methods.

Comment: @arshajii. Yes, Java 8 has default method, but I am not considering that here, assuming OP is not using Java 8 yet.

Comment: @Rohit Jain What occuring when we cast to `Number`: `Object obj = new Integer(5); Number num = (Number)obj;` in your example? Compiler parse `(Number)obj` as a some reference to `Number`?

Comment: @St.Antario. Compiler will add the cast, as you have said so explicitly. Compiler deals with the reference type. Now at runtime, the cast may fail or succeed, based on the actual object being referred to by the reference. Since in your case, the actual object is `new Integer(5);`, which you can easily assign to a `Number` reference, so the cast succeeds.

Comment: @St.Antario. The cast will also succeed if `obj = null;`, because `null` is a valid value for any reference.

Comment: @Rohit Jain What will be occur if we explicitly cast at compile time? What is `(Number)obj` at compile time? I think that it is some references to `Number` like for example `Number someNumber;` at compile time. Does all of casts invoking at run time?

Comment: @St.Antario. Casts are always done at runtime. With `(Number)obj`, you are just casting from reference type of `obj` to `Number`. I suggest you to go through this JLS section - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1

Comment: @Rohit Jain I want to realize how compiler casting from reference type `obj` to `Number`. Does compiler just considering `(Number)obj` as a some reference to `Number` or what?

Comment: @Rohit Jain _A conversion from type Thread to type Object requires no run-time action; Thread is a subclass of Object, so any reference produced by an expression of type Thread is a valid reference value of type Object._ For example `Integer ints= new Integer(2);Number n=ints;` Why compiler does know that `Integer` is subtype of `Number`? Does he checked source code of `Number` until he find `Integer` or all of subtype of `Number`?

Comment: @St.Antario Compiler looks out for the declaration of `Number` and `Integer`, and knows the `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`. What part is confusing you?

Comment: @Rohit Jain Ok, Thanks! Final question: In the case `Number num = (SomeType)obj` compiler look out for declaration Number and SomeType and checking is SomeType subtype of Number? Please answer yes or no.

Comment: @St.Antario. In a way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

> Why we cant define static method in interface?

Interfaces are designed to work with polymorphism, basically. Polymorphism  How would you know which implementation to call when calling a static method on an interface?

```
// Should that invoke MyClass.method or MyOtherImplementation.method?
MyInterface.method("foo");
```

Next:

> Why we cant implements method() with static modifier?

The idea is that the method is called on some object which implements the interface - which makes it an instance method.

> When we are calling myMethod with reference to Object we have compile error. As i understood, compiler doesnt cast automatically, isnt it?

No, the compiler doesn't cast automatically. There's no implicit conversion from `Object` to `Number`, so you can't call a method with a parameter of type `Number` with an argument of type `Object`.

> What compiler is doing when we cast to Number in this case?

It's validating that the value of `someObj` is either null or a reference to an instance of `Number` or a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

until JDK7:

1. because static methods are bound to the class. you normaly invoke them like this:

   ```
   MyClass.method("");
   ```

   you can not override them.
2. see 1 and all interface method are `public abstract` you can not change that!
3. no the compiler does not cast automatically
4. he tries to cast and fails