# companion object to a private class: why isn't it valid?

Tags: scala, types, companion-object

i needed two instances that has access to each other privates. i naturaly thought of a companion object that grants access to a one and only instance of it's companion class. the class itself i made private, so users cannot just create instances using `new`.

```
object A {
    def apply = dual
    lazy val dual = new A
}

private class A {
    //some irrelevant logic...
}
```

this code does not compile. i get: **class A escapes its defining scope as part of type A** error, which i don't really understand. my current workaround was to define a trait with every method declaration the class should have and make `class A` extend that trait, while *dual* is of the trait type, and not `class A` type.

what's the theoretic problem i'm missing here? why is this forbiden?

Comment: hehehe access to each others privates

Comment: @AK4749 well, after all it's her companion we're talking about. It's not like the class is just allowing _anyone_ to access her privates... Although upon _reflection_...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Paolo's solution is good (+1), but he didn't explain the error message, so let me try that. The problem stems from the fact that every method needs a return type. Your original definition of `apply` and `dual` returned an object of `class A`, thus the implicit return type of both was `A`. That implies that `A` must be visible to clients - how else could they call the function or access the `val`? Moreover, as both - and their parent object too - are public, they are globally visible. However, you declared `A private` which means it must not be visible outside its package. So there is a conflict which can't be resolved by the compiler.

The general rule is that all parameter and return type of functions / members must have (at least) the same scope of visibility as the referring member itself*. Thus one trivial way to solve this problem would be to reduce the visibility of `apply` and `dual` to `private`. This would satisfy the compiler, but not you :-)

Your solution gets around the problem by changing the static return type to a `public` trait, which thus has the same visibility as the members referring to it. The dynamic type of the returned object is still `class A`, however, this need not be visible to clients. This is a classic example of the principle ["program to interfaces, not implementations"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean).

Note that to apply this principle to the full extent, one could turn `class A` into a `private` inner class of `object A`, thus making it innaccessible even for other classes within the same package:

```
trait A {
    //...
}

object A {
    def apply: A = dual
    lazy val dual: A = new AImpl

    private class AImpl extends A {
        //some irrelevant logic...
    }

}
```

* <sub>To be pedantic, the enclosing class / object may reduce the visibility of its members, like here:</sub>

```
private class Holder {
  def member = new Hidden
}

private class Hidden
```

<sub>where `member` is `public` but its enclosing class is `private`, effectively hiding its members from the external world. So the compiler emits no complaints here.</sub>

Answer (score 25):

I think you don't want a private class, but a class with a private constructor.

```
class A private() 
object A {
    def apply = dual
    lazy val dual = new A
}
```

Now your class is "visible" to outside code, but only your companion object can create instances of it.

Comment: thanks! silly me... sometimes, the most puzzling problems, are actually kinda silly and simple.