# GWT: MVP Presenter Interface

Tags: gwt, interface, presenter

I try to understand how the gwt example about activities and places works (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces). I am wondering why they define an interface for the presenter. I know the view interface is helpful  to exchange the view easily. But what's the use of the presenter interface?

Answer (score 0):

Its always a best practice to design application with interfaces rather than concrete classes.

1. Reference - [What does "program to interfaces, not implementations" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean)
2. Reference - [WikiPedia example for MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

Comment: I agree absolutely with the statement about interfaces. But keep in mind that is is also possible to overuse interfaces (actually that's even considered an antipattern)

Answer (score 0):

Another key factor in [MVP architecture](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2?hl=te) to make your design pretty clean is defining an `Presenter interface`(As we already know the beauty  of interface `OOP concept`in `JAVA`).

`Presenter` interface that allows our `View` to `callback` into the `presenter` when it receives an event. The Presenter interface defines the following:

```
public interface Presenter<T> {
 void onAddButtonClicked(); 
}
```

And then you can set the presenter to your view  like  below

```
private Presenter<T> presenter;
  public void setPresenter(Presenter<T> presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
  }
```

Finally when your PresenterConcreteClass implements your `presenter` interface those `implementations` will triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the *cleanliness* of using an interface, there's also no reason you wouldn't test your view. You could use end-to-end tests, but you can also simply use a `GWTTestCase` where you instantiate the view and use a mock presenter.

You'd then be able to test that “when I click on this button, it should call this method from the presenter with the values X, Y and Z as arguments”, or “when I call this method of the view with those arguments, then such widget should turn red and that other one should hide/collapse/show/whatever”.

I've also used it, once, to similarly build a simple *testbed* app to manually test the UI with fake data. The app consisted of buttons to simulate the presenter calling the view with fake data, and handled the presenter calls back from the view with `Window.alert` or similar things. You'd launch the app in your browser and click here and there and validate that the view works as expected.

This can be useful when you later add a field to your form, to make sure you correctly *wire* it with the presenter. You don't want to setup your GWT-RPC/RequestFactory/whatever services from the real presenter, when a unit-test could be enough.

Comment: Do i need the presenter interface to mock it? Or is that also possible with the concrete presenter? And what do you mean with cleanliness?

Answer (score 0):

2 big reasons off the top of my head (there may be others too...)

1. **Testing**:  Your Presenter then does not have to have a direct reference to the View, which is nice because the View contains GWT Objects (i.e: any Widget) which cannot be used in a standard Unit Test Case:  Any GWT Object must have a JS container (i.e: Browser, or GWTTestCase) to be instantiated; A JUnit test case cannot use a Browser; **GWTTestCase runs VERY slow**, so you should prefer not to have to use it.  Without the interface, the Presenter would have to reference the View's methods by a direct reference to the View; that means when testing the Presenter, you must instantiate the View, which must instantiate its Widgets (which at that point require the GWTTestCase for the Widgets).  And all you should be aiming to do in the 1st place is to test the logic, which should be completely in the Presenter to avoid GWTTestCase... With the Display interface, you can do just that:  Focus on testing the Presenter, without the complication of instantiating the View (which has its own degree of instantation complication) and messing around then necessarily with GWTTestCase
2. **Have multiple Views for the same Presenter**:  [I think you would only ever do this if you have different platforms (i.e: mobile App vs. browser) which each require their own View (since a mobile App version of the View is rendered differently from a browser View, since they are different platforms with different GUI entities)].  The multiple Views would then all just implement the Display interface in their separate ways.  Then the single Presenter can contain the logic that is the same for all Views, be used for all the different Views, and all View implementations are guaranteed to follow the same expectations (which are the codification in the Display interface) of that single Presenter!  This is a manifestation of the OOP best practice of designing with interfaces, which @SSR Answers.