# Java generics on LHS but not on RHS of assignment

Tags: java, generics

I came across the following code and was wondering whether this is good practice:

```
LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList();
```

I would have written

```
List<String> l = new LinkedList<String> ();
```

So there are two questions here:

1. I always thought its good practice to use the type `List` and not `ArrayList`/`LinkedList`.
2. What exactly happens if you omit the diamond on the RHS of the assignment operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Always program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean), that way your code stays implementation independent.
2. You are creating the raw type, which will give you a warning, but it will compile. "LinkedList is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedList should be parameterized". It doesn't actually matter though because of erasure.

Comment: "It doesn't actually matter" - unless of course the constructor takes arguments of the omitted generic type(s).

Comment: No never omit it, that's why it gives a warning.