# List vs IEnumerable in private, lazy-loaded property

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, ienumerable, private-members

I have a public property (AllCustomers), which is backed by a private property for lazy loading.

I understand that the public property should be IEnumerable (["program to interfaces, not implementations"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean)).

However, I can see two ways to build the private property.

First option, with private List-

```
private List<Customer> _AllCustomers;
public IEnumerable<Customer> AllCustomers
{
    get
    {
        if (_AllCustomers == null)
        {
            _AllCustomers = DAL.GetAllCustomers().ToList(); 
        }
        return _AllCustomers;
    }
}
```

Second option, with private IEnumerable-

```
private IEnumerable<Customer> _AllCustomers;
public IEnumerable<Customer> AllCustomers
{
    get
    {
        if (_AllCustomers == null)
        {
            _AllCustomers = DAL.GetAllCustomers(); 
        }
        return _AllCustomers;
    }
}
```

I think the first option appears more correct, as it will hit the database once and store the results, whereas the second will result in multiple database hits.

My questions are-

- Am I correct in my analysis?
- What are the implications of the different approaches?
- Is there any time the second option would be preferred?
- Are there better, more idiomatic ways to express the
  second option?

Comment: We can't possibly answer without knowing what `DAL.GetAllCustomers()` does. It might return a `List<Customer>` for example, even if it's *declared* to return `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

Comment: And why your private members are properties, not fields?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Thanks, private members updated to fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet - So if DAL.GetAllCustomers() returns a List<Customer>, then there is no difference between the samples?

Comment: @Spongeboy: Not necessarily. The first version creates a copy of the list. `DAL.GetAllCustomers()` might be caching the list it returns, for example - in which case you could easily demonstrate different behaviour by casting the result of `AllCustomers` back to `List<Customer>` and modifying it.

Comment: If you have few customers, those alternatives are ok... but more probably you have a large number of data. in this case, you'll need to use `IQueryable` and paging mechanism (`Skip`, `Take`, `OrderBy`) to avoid out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several levels of "laziness" involved here. One is the inherent laziness of `IEnumerable` implementations, the other is the lazy implementation you add yourself to your property.

Your first implementation will hit the database once, the first time `AllCustomers` is accessed. It will construct the query in `GetAllCustomers` and perform it when you call `ToList`, storing the results locally.

Your second implementation will *also* hit the database only once (assuming your LINQ implementation is halfway decent). However, this will be *later* than in the first scenario - even calling your `AllCustomer` property will only return an `IQueryable`, which will only be performed when `AllCustomers` is actually accessed or enumerated. This might be immediately after, or not - it's a lazier implementation. Again, assuming your LINQ provider isn't too stupid, iterating over the entire collection will still only hit the DB once.

Why should you choose the first option anyway? Because (again, depending on the implementation), iterating over `AllCustomers` *twice* might hit the DB twice. Resharper, conveniently enough, warns us when we have a possible multiple enumeration of an `IEnumerable`. Storing it in a local `List` will ensure we keep a cached local copy. To make sure this is expressed explicitly in the code, consider exposing an `IReadOnlyList` instead of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Are you sure about your statement `iterating over the entire collection will still only hit the DB once.`? It is absolutely wrong, LINQ provider returns IQueryable which hit DB on every enumeration.

Comment: @AkashKava You're right, and I was unclear. It will hit the DB once for every enumeration, but not for every iteration of that enumeration. I might have misunderstood the OP's concerns in that case, but I think my edit clears that up.

Comment: Well even for every iteration, the reader is still open. So enumerating over Query keeps DB connection open. It is still better to call ToList and then enumerate on it.

Comment: That depends on the LINQ provider, as @MarcinJuraszek states in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both will hit the DB only once as the `_AllCustomers` backing field is only `NULL` when the getter is called for the first time.

As a matter of personal preference I'm usually preferring `IEnumerable` in my interface and method declarations, however backing fields are concrete classes, e.g. `List<stuff>`. Makes things like modifying your collections amongst others easier.

Comment: No, the second one *might* hit the database each time the customers are requested. We can't know, because we don't know how `DAL.GetAllCustomers()` is implemented. It might return a query which will execute each time, or it might return a materialized list...

Comment: If GetAllCustomers returns an IQueryable then it will hit DB everytime.

Comment: @AkashKava Not necessary. You can return `List<T>` as `IQueryable<T>` using `AsQueryable` method.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Even after AsQueryable the instance of List is still a List not query to database.

Comment: @AkashKava Yes, what makes your *If it return `IQueryable` it will hit DB everytime* invalid. There is a chance that DB will be hit only once even when method is declared to return `IQueryable`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It is implied that IQueryable is query to database, no idiot uses List and cast it to IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that the public property should be IEnumerable ("program to interfaces, not implementations").

This understanding is flawed.  The principle of programming to interfaces doesn't say *which* interface you should program to.  In your example. I would expose `IList<T>`, and make it readonly assuming you don't want consumers to modify the list:

```
private List<Customer> _AllCustomers;
public IList<Customer> AllCustomers
{
    get
    {
        if (_AllCustomers == null)
        {
            _AllCustomers = DAL.GetAllCustomers().ToList().AsReadOnly(); 
        }
        return _AllCustomers;
    }
}
```

Comment: But IList is less permissive than IEnumerable, the "program to interfaces" principle to use the most permissive. I understand IList should be used if the data contract implies that random access is required.

Comment: @Spongeboy: I can see the argument for being permissive with method parameters.  But I would only use a return value of IEnumerable<T> if I wanted to hint to the caller that the implementation may use lazy evaluation.  Returning IList<T> or ICollection<T> makes it easier for the caller (Count property, easier to iterate repeatedly).