# How do I initialize an arrayList<Integer> within a object declaration

Tags: java, arraylist

Chest is a different class which I want to make into an object, inside the chest class I just want to declare it with a bunch of values including an ArrayList which will be ints

How can I format this correctly? Thank you so much for any help!

It doesn't compile correctly.

```
Chest chest = new Chest(0,0,0, {0},false,false);
```

Hopefully this makes sense what I'm trying to do

this is the arrayList in the other class

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Chest
{
   public ArrayList<Integer> idList;
   public boolean closed;
   public boolean opened;

   public Chest(int xpos, int ypos, int numContents, ArrayList<Integer> idList, boolean opened, boolean closed)
   {
     this.closed = true;
     this.opened = false;
   }

 }
```

How I fixed it

```
Chest chest = new Chest(0,0,0, new ArrayList<Integer>(),false,false);
```

Thank you micha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Chest chest = new Chest(0, 0, 0, new ArrayList<Integer>(), false, false);
```

If you want to to add values to the list you can use `Arrays.asList()` as a shortcut:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
Chest chest = new Chest(0, 0, 0, list, false, false);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much for quick and simple fix!

Comment: Note that the List returned by Arrays.asList is not resizable

Answer (score 2):

A simple way:

```
chest = new Chest(0,0,0, Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7),false,false);
```

This will cause a problem with `ArrayList<Integer> idList` in your constructor though. You should [probably change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean) that to `List<Integer> idList`.

If not, you can use

`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7))` as my original answer showed.

See: [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Comment: why new ArrayList, why not just Arrays.asList()?

Comment: @eis: good question. That combination is ingrained in my memory but now I don't know why it ever was like that..

Comment: Might be due to fact that Arrays.asList() will give a fixed size list, you'd need to use new ArrayList for a mutable list. However, I think in this case read-only list should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it with:

```
new Chest(0, 0, 0, Arrays.asList(0), false, false)
```

Note that the return type is `List<Integer>` rather than `ArrayList<Integer>`, which is probably what you want anyway.  There's probably no need to specify which specific implementation of the interface `List` to use in the class declaration.

If you want to initialize it to an empty list, you can use:

```
new Chest(0, 0, 0, Collections.emptyList(), false, false)
```

Note in both cases, you get an immutable list.