# Should I use ViewModel for elements collection: IList, IEnumerable or List type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Should I use use in ViewModel for elements collection: IList, IEnumerable or List type?

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class NoteWithCommentsViewModel
{
    public Notes Note { get; set; }
    public IList<Comments> Comments { get; set; } //Maybe it should be: List or IEnumerable?
}
```

This is my controller:

```
var note = _notesService.GetNote(friendlyUrl);
var comments = _commentsService.GetNoteCommentsWithoutSpam(note.NoteId).ToList();

var noteWithCommentsViewModel = new NoteWithCommentsViewModel
{
    Note = note,
    Comments = comments
};
```

In view I iterate over Comments - so IEnumerable should be enought in ViewModel but in controller I must execute query using ToList() so maybe I should use List or IList in ViewModel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "program to interfaces, not implementations" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean)

Comment: so should I use IList or IEnumerable in ViewModel?

Comment: Why must you use .ToList() in the controller?

Comment: You should use the most abstract possible type that allows you to do everything that you need to do.