# Iterable<Key> as return type, what does this mean?

Tags: java, interface, return

I am reading about the sequentialsearch implementation [SequentialSearch](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/31elementary/SequentialSearchST.java.html)
, found something that makes little sense (or at least in my opinion it seems so)

```
    public Iterable<Key> keys()  {
    Queue<Key> queue = new Queue<Key>();
    for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        queue.enqueue(x.key);
    return queue;
}
```

How can a method return a Interface? shouldn't we return a class/ primitive type?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be able to have an interface as its return type?

Comment: what does it mean then? the object returned must implement that interface ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an example of polymorphism. 
Means that reference to object of any class implementing the interface can be returned from this method.

This design is used in case the method is meant to be overridden by subclasses.
The method signature represents a contract that all subclasses overriding this method should return their specific implementation of the interface mentioned in the method signature.

Comment: Technically, *a reference to* an object of any class implementing that interface, or null.

Comment: @GauravPal if you explain key words a little more, I would gladly vote u up

Answer (score 1):

Not only **can** the method return an interface, it **should**.

The client who calls the method presumably needs a "group" (I used that word to be language agnostic and avoid collision with something like set/list/collection) of `Key`s that he can iterate through and do things with.  If all he needs to do is iterate through them, then give him an `Iterable`.  Then you, the maintainer of the `keys()` method, are free to evolve it over time to use a different, perhaps more efficient, implementation under the covers.  The client will be blissfully unaware of your implementation changes.

This is one of the very most important OO design paradigms you can and should internalize: [program to interfaces, not implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean)

Answer (score 0):

`A method returning an interface` means that you can return an instance of any class that implements the interface.