# Designing class for handling multiple communication protocols handling

Tags: c++, design-patterns, server-communication

I am developing a C++ application which should handle multiple communication protocols (Ethernet, Serial, etc.). Each of the communication protocols is handled as a specific class.
In order to expose as little as possible information about the internal structure and organization of the said classes and protocols, I would like to somehow wrap all of this functionality and provide somewhat generic API for sending data over a selected protocol.

Basically, what API should provide (the parameters are not restricted to this, but is the general idea):

```
bool sendData(uint8_t* buffer, const size_t& bufferSize);

void receiveData(uint8_t* dataBuffer, size_t& bufferSize);
```

What is the best way to create a generic API for the said functionality, and if possible involve some design pattern?

Regards.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward use case for inheritance from an abstract `class`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @StephenNewell well yes, i have been looking into the factory design pattern, but I am not 100% sure if that is, by design and usage of that pattern, correct way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to create a generic API for the said
>   functionality, and if possible involve some design pattern?

[The Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) looks suitable in this scenario.

First, define an *interface* for all your distinct communication startegies,  `Communication`:

```
class Communication {
public:
   virtual ~CommunicationStrategy() = default;
   virtual bool sendData(uint8_t* buffer, const size_t& bufferSize) = 0;
   virtual void receiveData(uint8_t* dataBuffer, size_t& bufferSize) = 0;
};
```

Then, your concrete implementations – i.e., *strategies* – should derive from this interface:

```
class EthernetCommunication: public Communication {
public:
   // ...
   bool sendData(uint8_t*, const size_t&) override;
   void receiveData(uint8_t*, size_t&) override;
};

class SerialCommunication: public Communication {
public:
   // ...
   bool sendData(uint8_t*, const size_t&) override;
   void receiveData(uint8_t*, size_t&) override;
};

class CarrierPigeon: public Communication {
public:
   // ...
   bool sendData(uint8_t*, const size_t&) override;
   void receiveData(uint8_t*, size_t&) override;
};
```

The client code will work with a (pointer to) `Communication` – i.e., the interface – rather than directly with a particular implementation like `EthernetCommunication`, `SerialCommunication`, or `CarrierPigeon`. Thus, the code follows the ["program to an interface, not to an implementation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean) advice. For example, you may have a factory function like:

```
std::unique_ptr<Communication> CreateCommunication();
```

This factory function returns one of the strategies above. Which strategy to return can be determined at run time.

```
std::unique_ptr<Communication> com = CreateCommunication();
// send data regardless of a particular communication strategy
com->sendData(buffer, bufferSize);
```

This way, the code above isn't coupled to any particular implementation, but only to the interface `Communication` which is common to all the different possible communication strategies.

---

If the different communication strategies don't need per-instance data, just having two callbacks instead of an object will do:

```
using data_sender_t = bool (*)(uint8_t*, const size_t&);
using data_receiver_t = void (*)(uint8_t*, size_t&);

// set these function pointers to the strategy to use
data_sender_t data_sender;
data_receiver_t data_receiver;
```

Comment: This seems that it will be a good approach. I think I'll need to have more than one callback function per instance.

edit: Is it possible to add functionality which is not common for both classes?

Comment: @RobertŠandor The object-based approach is more general than the callback-based one. The latter you generally use when you only encapsulate behavior.

Comment: I used this pattern for exactly this purpose, it works well:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/classmuscle_1_1DataIO.html

Comment: @RobertŠandor you can implement additional member functions in a concrete implementation that aren't part of the `Communication` interface. However, if the client code works with this implementation through the (common) interface, it can only call the member functions exposed by the interface.