# Calling another repository directly from a service?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on a project with a service, repository pattern. AService, ARepository, BService, BRepository. Now, however, it happens that A has a relation to B. So I have to shoot another query against the B database to merge both objects later. For example: give me all objects A and their relation to object B. Can I call the BRepository directly from the AService or should I better go via the BService? Is there a rule here according to cleanCode?

Comment: I'd suggest viewing [Sandro Mancuso : Crafted Design](https://vimeo.com/107963074), especially from minute 10:40. There are what he calls _"actions"_ (also known as _use-cases_, or _application services_) and _"domain services"_ and their relationships. PS: You shouldn't restrict the use of a certain service to the use of a certain [repository](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Comment: @dakis Thanks for your comment and the link. i will have a look. What do you mean by "PS: You should not restrict the use of a particular service to the use of a particular repository." You mean that a repository should be accessible for several services?

Comment: Yes, this is, indeed, what I meant. Though, you should try to follow the principles from the video presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can. Imagine situation, when user buy something in online shop. You would need many repositories:

```
public  class OrderService
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private IWareHouseRepository _wareHouseRepository;
    
    OrderService(IUserRepository userRepository,
        IWareHouseRepository wareHouseRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _wareHouseRepository = wareHouseRepository;
    }
}
```

I would prefer to call repository instead of service because repository is less specific. I mean calling another service `ServiceB` that contain desired repository can be dangerous as business logic can be added into existing service `ServiceB` which is not eligible for your `ServiceA`.

In addition, circular dependencies can be occured if we call service from another service. So try to use dependency injection. Moreover, try to [program to interfaces, not implementations](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean), I mean you can create interfaces for your service classes and use this interface from your client classes (pass the concrete implementation to the constructor).

Comment: Thank you for your good answer! I will have to think about it some more but it sounds logical. Why do you think dependency injection should be used?

Comment: @MaxPattern as it is better sometimes program to interface and writing unit tests will become  easier