# I have a problem with understanding the task about logging in java for this project. What does the task mean?

Tags: java, logging

[Image with task of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoU5L.png)

I have received a project from my university and i now have to implement a couple of features. I got stuck at this task because i don't know what the second paragraph means. I have imported the "libraries" for log files and it works fine. I can print in the console stuff like:
logger.INFO("This is some info");

where do i go from here?
do i just have to implement pertinent logger's for each function in my code?

This is the rep in GitHub: https://github.com/mirelvitel/Training_PasswordSafeConsole_Java.git

Comment: please don't expect us to go through your assignment. ask specific questions here, with all relevant information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "program to interfaces, not implementations" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean)

Comment: Interesting task, sounds like simplified reverse-engineering of SLF4J