# I have this code with a class which has a method with type of inteface created in my project , anyone know what does it mean?

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, interface

Here is my class with the interface type method

```
internal class MyClass
    {
        public static IMainInterface MyMethod(Main main)
        {
           ///some code
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: Well why would I define a method with type of Interface ?

Comment: That interface is the return type of the method. That means it returns you a reference to one.

Comment: Methods don't have types. The **return value** has a type.

Comment: `MyMethod` wants one argument of type `Main` and returns any instance of a class which implements `IMainInterface`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the method returns an instance of a class that implements the `IMainInterface` interface.

This is often done for [design reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean); in particular, it's usually a good practice to program to interfaces rather than concrete implementations. By analogy, when you learn to drive, you learn to drive cars "in general", not just a Ford Focus. You know how to use all cars to the extent that their interface is the same.