# Why when we init dependency in module we waiting for interface type and not actual object type? - Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Please someone explain me why when we use dependency injection and initialize the object in the module the provides function return type is interface but in body function we return the actual object. This is example

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providePrefsManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context): PrefsManager {
    return PrefsManagerImpl(context)
}
```

Why here we return `PrefsManager` instead of `PrefsManagerImpl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code to the interface, not the implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2697783/1426891) `@Provides` methods  provide according to their return values, so if you return PrefsManagerImpl, Dagger will only know how to inject PrefsManagerImpl. By returning PrefsManager, Dagger lets you inject PrefsManager directly, so the injecting class doesn't need to be aware of PrefsManagerImpl or any other implementation at all.

---

More specifically to dependency injection: The concept behind dependency injection is that, for the class you're writing, it's the *caller* or *DI framework* that controls which instance or implementation your class receives. This is an "inversion of control" compared to a self-contained class that maintains complete control of which classes or dependencies it uses.

As such, the class you're writing should be *as general as possible* when specifying its dependencies, which gives you flexibility about which implementations you can supply.

For example: If you need a sort algorithm, it would defeat the flexibility of dependency injection if you always asked specifically for a hypothetical MyBinarySortImpl; instead, you should make your request more general, such as injecting an interface like BinarySorter or Sorter (both also hypothetical). Your caller or dependency injection framework can still supply a MyBinarySortImpl, but by being as general as possible you also free your caller to supply a WellTestedNativeBinarySortImpl or a VeryFastRadixSortImpl. If your implementation *needs* to be a binary sort, you can specify that, and if it doesn't you can leave it general.

In your specific case, your `@Provides` method provides a binding of PrefsManager; the implementation happens to be a PrefsManagerImpl. However, the class that consumes PrefsManager is asserting that it doesn't need anything specific to PrefsManagerImpl, it can work when it only uses the interface as described through PrefsManager. That injecting class can now be tested using a FakePrefsManager or a mocking-framework-created `mock(PrefsManager)`, or even a wrapper you could write like `LoggingPrefsManager(PrefsManagerImpl(context))`. By operating through interfaces rather than implementations, it keeps your options open.

Comment: thank you for explanation. but why `val someManager : SomeManager = SomeManagerImpl()` works? Why we can set interface = real class?

Comment: The specific reason is that in Java the `someManager` is a [reference variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) that can can be assigned compatible values; instances of classes that subclass a class (`extends`) or implement an interface (`implements`) are compatible with the base. The general concept is called [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). It's a core tenet of [object-oriented programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and has been built into Java from the beginning.