# php class, method from file

Tags: php

how insert method in class from another file?
Now i get error:

`T_FUNCTION' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 9

```
    index.php file:
    <?php

    class cars
    {
        public function go()
        {
            echo 'go go';
        }    
        include('stop.php');
    }

    $c = new cars;
    $c->go();
    ?>

    stop.php file
    <?php
    public function stop()
    {
        echo 'stop method';
    }

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I include code into a PHP class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class)

Comment: Making my answer CW because it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in PHP.

You would have to create multiple classes that extend each other:

```
class cars_base
 {....}
```

stop.php:

```
class cars_base_1 extends cars_base
 {....}
```

but this is rarely practical. Much rather try to build an object structure that is easy to split into separate modules that do not need to extend each other - or, if it clearly belongs into the same class, live with a lot of code in one file. With a good IDE, that's not that much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in PHP, include doesn't work like a macro.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 will support Traits, which offer what you want. But in the current stable version of PHP best you cen do is inheritance ;)

Comment: Wow.  Never heard of this, and now I WANT.