# Why I can't divide a class over several files

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm trying to create a class `TestClass` that's divided over several files. I have split it over 3 files where the first file `TestClassPart1.php` has the start of the class `class TestClass {` and the last file `TestClassPart3.php` has the closing bracket of the class. These are the 3 files

```
//TestClassPart1.php
<?php  
class TestClass {    
   public function func1(){ 
      echo "func 1"; 
   }

//TestClassPart2.php
<?php    
   public function func2(){ echo "func 2"; }

//TestClassPart3.php
<?php    
   public function func3(){ echo "func 3"; }

}
```

I then recombine in the actual class file called `TestClass.php`so TestClass.php is just the glue of all 3 files.

```
<?php
require 'TestClassPart1.php';
require 'TestClassPart2.php';
require 'TestClassPart3.php';
```

I thought this should work, but when I try to create an instance of `TestClass` and call one of the functions, I get `parse error, expecting T_FUNCTION' in C:\wamp\www\TestClassPart1.php on line 5`. Line 5 is the `}` of `func1()`

```
<?php
require 'TestClass.php';
$nc = new TestClass();
$nc->func1();
```

Shouldn't this work? I thought you could spread a class over several files no problem. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If the class is so big it's not manageable within a single file, then it's probably ripe for refactoring or decomposing into smaller classes.

Comment: Isn't the "quick solution" to tag the class (if you're using phpdoc or equivalent) with a todo and then go back to it when you have the time/opportunity? i.e.: Leave it as it is rather than providing the illusion of addressing the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you `require` a file, PHP will parse and evaluate the contents.

You class is incomplete, so when PHP parses

```
class TestClass {    
   public function func1(){ 
      echo "func 1"; 
   }
```

it's not able to make sense of the class, because the closing } is missing.

**Simple as that.**

---

And to anticipate your next question. This

```
class Foo
{
    include 'methods.php'
}
```

will not work either.

---

From the [PHP Manual on OOP 4](http://de.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php) (couldnt find it in 5)

> You can NOT break up a class definition into multiple files. You also can NOT break a class definition into multiple PHP blocks, unless the break is within a method declaration. The following will not work:

```
<?php
class test {
?>
<?php
    function test() {
        print 'OK';
    }
}
?>
```

> However, the following is allowed:

```
<?php
class test {
    function test() {
        ?>
        <?php
        print 'OK';
    }
}
?>
```

---

If you are looking for [Horizontal Reuse, either wait for PHP.next, which will include Traits](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse) or have a look at

- [Can I include code into a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class/1957830#1957830)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same thought a while back as a purely academic interest. It's not directly possible to do what you're asking, although you are able to use PHP to produce PHP that then gets evaluated by the server.

Long story short:

## Don't bother

Short story long:

- it adds a level of insecurity to your classing system as it becomes harder to control file access.
- it slows down the compilation/caching of pages
- you really don't need to force a square peg into a round hole.

Instead: use proper OOP practices of separating functionality into classes and extending existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* do it this way, you can use `include_once()` to directly shove a file into your script.

Comment: not quite. The PHP has to be well-formed to execute. In this case the php will be invalid, as the closing bracket will be missing.

Comment: I was thinking that those were just misprinted lines of code. The files are actually structured this way? Ouch. I would just rethink how I'm coding, as I see no use for doing this.