# issue when printing class's variables

Tags: php, oop

I'm creating a system like MVC. 
I'm using below class when I want to call view files.
Edit: Meantime, He can do this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Aw28-krO7ZM#t=1166s

```
<?php 
class Call{    
    function __construct($fileName) {
        //$this->db = new Database;
        self::callFile($fileName);
    }

    function callFile($fileName)
    {
        $this->title = "example";
        $this->description = "example";
        $this->keywords = "example";
        $fileName = $fileName . '.php';
        require PAGESPATH.'common/header.php';
        require PAGESPATH.$fileName;
        require PAGESPATH.'common/footer.php';
    }
}
?>
```

$fileName is index.php. Index.php has only

```
Index Page..
```

I want to print data in header.php like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php if(isset($this->title)){echo $this->title;} ?> - WebProgramlama.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php if(isset($this->description)){echo $this->description;}?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php if(isset($this->keywords)){echo $this->keywords;} ?>" />
   </head>
   <body>
```

But I'm getting errors.

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/webprogramlama/class/pages/common/header.php on line 4
```

What can i solve this problem?
Note: Please be careful! header.php is calling by Call class. header.php is inside of Call class.

Edit: And Why [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/94293626/orn.zip) is running?

Comment: And what object do you think `$this` in your template should refer to?

Comment: Please don't create something if you don't even know basic concepts. Your code is broken beyond repair.

Comment: @webarto I bet you know anthing about OOP.

Answer (score 3):

Stop watching that stupid "tutorial". It is so bad that at one point i actually begun to laugh.

You cannot just pick up a language, without any previous experience, and just start using high-level concepts. MVC is one of such concepts. To actually grasp it you need to understand object oriented programming and a lot of principles, that are associated with it.

- [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
- [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter)
- [Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)
- [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

.. etc. And you wont understand those principles just by reading the articles.

As for how to solve your problem, you could read [this article](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). It will explain how to use templates. Which is actually what your "mvc tutorial" there actually is - bad guide for making routing mechanism and templates.

Also, you must understand that, if you do `self::something();`, it is outside an object. You are calling a static method on a class, which actually is just poor way of doing procedural programming.

You should start by learning the [**basics of OOP**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in PHP, because you don't get it. And for your own good, stay away from MVC and frameworks for a year at least.

Comment: But I'm trying to use $this->CallFile($fileName) I'm getting same problem.

Comment: Now what is just a lie. http://viperpad.com/stip2p and http://viperpad.com/gvReiF . Of course, if you are rendering output in the constructor (as seems to be your intention), **you are doing it WRONG !**

Comment: Call.class.php: http://ideone.com/1C5qF And I'm calling Call.class.php as: http://ideone.com/UX2Tb

Comment: Please go and learn OOP. Classes are not just "different kind of functions".

Comment: It is running because it has no mistakes.

Comment: Ok Then Where is the mistakes. I create a question at stackoverflow because I can't find mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the elements as `$this->title` outside the class, you need to create a new instance of the object in your code this like:

```
$callObject= new call($filename);
```

then refer to it in the page like this:

```
$callObject->title;
```

You can only use the `$this->` code inside the class itself. Anywhere else, you need to make an object and therefore `$this` doesn't exist - the object of that class does - and you then have to refer to it by its name. At the same time, if your variable is going to be called `$callObject` you can't refer to it like that *inside* the class - as at that point you haven't made an instance of it, so you need to refer to it via the `$this` syntax which is a nice way of saying `my element called title`.

Edit: okay, I see what you are doing now, goodness me.

That's rather dangerous because your header.php file will contain loads of things that will *only* work inside the class called class - and generate hideous errors in every single other circumstance.

PHP will let you have the `header.php` file as it is, but as PHP evaluates the contents as it goes, your object is incomplete. You should have a [read of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607181/why-i-cant-divide-a-class-over-several-files) which will answer that part in more detail.

Edit 2: Don't split a function between files.

If the code inside `header.php` is written be *only* used within the function (as it seems to be) copy the entire contents of it inside the class - and don't use a `require` or `include` to try to paste it in on the fly.

Never have more than one file for a class. It doesn't matter how long the file is.

Edit 3:

This is what your code should look like for the header section:

```
<?php 
class Call{    
    function __construct($fileName) {
    //$this->db = new Database;
    self::callFile($fileName);
    }

    function callFile($fileName)
    {
    $this->title = "example";
    $this->description = "example";
    $this->keywords = "example";
    $fileName = $fileName . '.php';
    echo "
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>        
    ";
    echo (isset($this->title)) ? $this->title : "";
    echo "
 - WebProgramlama.tk</title>
    <meta name='description' content='
    ";
    echo (isset($this->description)) ? $this->description : "";
    echo "' />
    <meta name='keywords' content='
    ";
    echo (isset($this->contents)) ? $this->contents : "";
    echo "
' />
   </head>
   <body>
    ";

    //require PAGESPATH.$fileName;
    //require PAGESPATH.'common/footer.php';
    // you can only include files that don't use any $this-> type elements.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No. Be careful. I'm calling header.php in Call class.

Comment: I can't understand. How can i print these datas? :) Meantime, I can't print $fileName in header.php

Answer (score 1):

`$this` has no context outside of the class. Create an instance of your class and use that instead.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
    $class = new Call('filename');
?>    
    <title><?php if(isset($class->title)){echo $class->title;} ?> - WebProgramlama.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php if(isset($class->description)){echo $class->description;}?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php if(isset($class->keywords)){echo $class->keywords;} ?>" />
   </head>
   <body>
```

Get rid of your `require` statements in your `callFile` function; they have no place being there.

Comment: Congratulations, you've broken what is already broken. No offense :)

Comment: No. Be careful. I'm calling header.php in Call class.