# how to get database credentials from config file in a php class

Tags: php

I want to create a file in which database credentials are stored.
How can I access that data in a php class since include in class body doesn't work?

Comment: _..since include in class body doesn't work..._ how comes? That is false. Take a  look at [include-code-into-a-php-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957732/can-i-include-code-into-a-php-class)

Comment: Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is you create a file dbconf.php and add db credentials as constants. e.g:

```
<?php // dbconf.php

define('DB_HOST','127.0.0.1');
define('DB_UER','root');
define('DB_PASS','password');
define('DB_NAME','your_database_name');
```

Then include this file and you can use these constants anywhere in your project.